# Can I limit out-going by URL?

Tags: networking, server, apache2, iptables

I have a problem with my Ubuntu-server , It is burce-forcing other servers and I was unable to solve till now.

Server is newly rebuilt but there are still PHP files from old server.

```
/var/log/apache/pucorp.org.log:---my-ip-here-- - - [29/Aug/2019:01:32:16 +0200] "POST wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 1580 "-""Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101
```

I want to limit buy URL to other IP's but allow my own.

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m string --string "/xmlrpc.php" --algo kmp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m string --string "/wp-login.php" --algo kmp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

This solved my xmlrpc error , but I can't access my own wp-login.php now.
If possible , I want to limit outgoind by URL for a while until I can solve and clear scripts.

Comment: Server is not , new built and migrated but there are still unwanted PHP files.

Comment: Then why not stop the webserver until you clean it up?

Comment: I did already off -the -web but still need to ban outgoing url

Comment: you may consider using fail2ban and its builtin wordpress rules

Comment: just add an ACCEPT rule for your own IP before the REJECT rule.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a problem with my Ubuntu-server , It is burce-forcing other servers and I was unable to solve till now.
>
> Server is newly rebuilt but there are still PHP files from old server.

You effectively copied the ***actual*** malware from the old to the new server. You don't need firewall rules. You need to take your site offline ***now*** and fix the problems before you take it online again.

This probably involves a clean wordpress install, copying over *parts* of `wp-content` that has media content, and manually reading through a database dump to check for unknown users, options, php content and so forth.

Firewall rules to limit this is the *wrong* approach.